# how to create a software store

Tags: java, database

how to create a software store like filehippo, getintopc,etc.
but, not a big level, just for a start. I need to know how to create a software station so that my client systems can access those softwares.
(without using an option of shared folder)

Comment: Too broad, this is not how things work here, just asking "How do I do X" will invite you for down votes and close votes. Breakdown your problem, make an attempt and ask specific `programming` question which can be answered in a single paragraph.

Comment: You are asking volunteers to come here and design this. Design questions are off-topic and can lead to opinionated answers and discussions which is not what this site is for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm welcoming your interest to create software store.Don't try to do like competitors.try in the different manner like cloud storage like [Filecoffee.com](http://www.filecoffee.com) i'm ready to help you on engineering for download store.